# Problem with changing a global variable in a onclick function in javascript / php

Tags: javascript, php, function, onclick, global-variables

The changing of the global variable `test10` in the `onclick` function is somehow not triggered (but the rest of the function works).
So the text box shows me still a *3* not a wanted *1*.  How can I fix this?

The function works with no problem without the onclick included in the function, but that doesn't really help me.
I have tried much other nonsense but it was nothing worth, I am really stuck here.

```js
var test10 = 3;
jQuery(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
...
    test10 = 1;
...
})

$('#text1').text(test10);
```

And there is no error message, it just doesn't return the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to read your post with the formatting the way it is, but it looks like you're not setting the output text inside the click handler function, are you? So when you click the document, it'll change the value of the variable, but the output is never updated. Copy the `$('#text1').text(test10);` inside the handler function and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute this script:

```
var test10 = 3;
jQuery(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
...
    test10 = 1;
...
})

$('#text1').text(test10);
```

**you actually do this:**

```
var test10 = 3;
$('#text1').text(test10);
```

***When the onclick event is triggered you set the variable `test10` to 1***, but then the above code

```
$('#text1').text(test10);
```

***has already been executed.***

To see the value of the global variable when you click you have to do something like this:

```
var test10 = 3;
jQuery(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
...
    test10 = 1;
    $('#text1').text(test10);
...
})
```